# Count Parenthesis in a file with a Python program?

Tags: python, exception, file, parentheses

I Wanna fix a function through it i can count how many times are used the:(,),[,]
if the counts of ( are equal to those of )
and if the counts of [ are equal to those of ]
then i have valid syntax!

my first -dissapointed- try:

```
filename=input("Give a file name:")

def  parenthesis(filename):
    try:
        f=open(filename,'r')
    except (IOError):
        print("The file",filename,"does not exist!False! Try again!")
    else:
         while True:
            for line in filename:
                line=f.readline()
                if line=='(':
                     c1=line.count('(')
                elif line==')':
                     c2=line.count(')')
                elif line=='[':
                     c3=line.count('[')
                elif line==']':
                     c4=line.count(']')
                elif line=='':
                    break

                if c1==c2:
                     print("Line: Valid Syntax")
                elif c1!=c2:
                     print("Line: InValid Syntax")
                elif c3==c4:
                     print("Line: Valid Syntax")
                elif c3!=c4:
                     print("Line: InValid Syntax")
    finally:
        f.close()

parenthesis(filename)
```

Comment: Is `) somestuff (` syntactically valid?

Comment: I'm not sure you have a complete question here. I understand what you are trying to do, but what aspect troubles you? Or, are you simply looking for someone to provide the code to do what you desire?

Comment: Aside from the issue of dealing properly with cases such as ") then (" and also parenthesis and such within string literals, you got a bunch of logic error in the code: for line in filename  will enumerate characters in the filename string !   then, the "lines" are effectively lines and cannot be compared to a single character. then the c1, c2, c3, c4 variables need to see the counts cumulated into them: as written they just will collect the values corresponding to the last line count...

Comment: Doesn't this looks a lot like homework ?

Comment: maybe...if you're experienced!
but im'not ...so... :(

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, neither the question nor any of the answers exhibit any concern about parentheses/brackets/braces/whatever inside a string constant. IOW the answers can't check themselves. Where is the bulk downvote button?

Answer (score 4):

Please excuse the length of this reply.

If I understand you correctly, you want to do simple syntax
checking of parentheses to make sure they are balanced correctly.
In your question you specify a test based on simple counting, but
as others have pointed out, this does not catch things like
"([)]".

I'd also like to offer some constructive criticism on other
aspects of your code.

To start with, it is better to get the filename from the command
line, and not to prompt for it. This is so that you can easily
run the program repeatedly, when developing it, without having
to type in the filename all the time. This is your way:

> $ **python foo.py**
>   Give a file name:**data**
>   [some output]
>   $ python foo.py
>   Give a file name:**data**
>   [some output]
>   $ python foo.py
>   Give a file name:**data**
>   [some output]

You need to type in the filename every time. You don't need to type
in the command to run the program more than once. After the first
time, you can use the arrow key to get it from the shell's command
history. If you get the filename from the command line, you can do
this instead:

> $ **python foo.py testfile**
>   [some output]
>   $ python foo.py testfile
>   [some output]
>   $ python foo.py testfile
>   [some output]

This way, when you test the second time, you don't need to type more
than the up arrow and Enter keys. This is a small convenience, but
it is important: when you're developing software, even small 
things can start annoying. It's like a large grain of sand under your
foot when going on a long walk: you won't even notice it for the first
couple of kilometers, but after a few more, you're bleeding.

In Python, to access the command line arguments, you need the
`sys.argv` list. The relevant changes to your program:

```
import sys
filename = sys.argv[1]
```

If you do want to prompt, you should use something else than the
built-in `input` function. It interprets whatever the user types
as a Python expression, and that causes all sorts of problems.
You could read using `sys.stdin.readline`.

Anyway, we've now got the name of the file safely stored in
the `filename` variable. It's time to do something with it.
Your `parentheses` function does pretty much everything, and
experience has shown that that's often not the best way of
doing things. Every function should, instead, do just one
thing, but do that well.

I suggest that you should keep the parts of actually opening
and closing a file separate from the actual counting. This
will simplify the logic of the counting, since it does not
need to worry about the rest. In code:

```
import sys

def check_parentheses(f):
    pass # we'll come to this later

def main():
    filename = sys.argv[1]
    try:
        f = file(filename)
    except IOError:
        sys.stderr.write('Error: Cannot open file %s' % filename)
        sys.exit(1)
    check_parentheses(f)
    f.close()

main()
```

I changed a couple of other things, too, in addition to rearranging
things. First, I write the error message to the standard error output.
This is the proper way to do it, and means fewer surprises to shell
users to redirect the output. (If that doesn't make any sense to you,
don't worry about it, just accept it as a given for now.)

Second, if there's an error, I exit the program with `sys.exit(1)`.
This tells whoever started the program that it failed. In Unix
shell, this lets you do things like the following:

```
if python foo.py inputfile
then
    echo "inputfile is OK!"
else
    echo "inputfile is BAD!"
fi
```

The shell script might do something more interesting than just reporting
success or failure, of course. It might, for example, remove all
broken files, or e-mail whoever wrote them to ask them to fix them.
The beauty is that you, who write the checker program, do not need
to care. You just set the program exit code properly, and let whoever
writes the shell script to worry about the rest.

The next step is to actually read the contents of the file. This
can be done in various ways. The easiest way is to do it line-by-line,
like this:

```
for line in f:
    # do something with the line
```

We then need to look at each character in the line:

```
for line in f:
    for c in line:
        # do something with the character
```

We're now ready to actually start checking parentheses. As suggested
by others, a **stack** is the appropriate data structure for this.
A stack is basically a list (or array) where you add items to one
end, and take them out in reverse order. Think of it as a stack of
coins: you can add a coin to the top, and you can remove the topmost
coin, but you can't remove one from the middle or bottom.

(Well, you can, and it's a neat trick if you do, but computers are
simple beasts and get upset by magic tricks.)

We will use a Python list as a stack. To add an item, we use
the list's `append` method, and to remove we use the `pop` method.
An example:

```
stack = list()
stack.append('(')
stack.append('[')
stack.pop() # this will return '['
stack.pop() # this will return '('
```

To look at the topmost item in the stack, we use `stack[-1]` (in
other words, the last item in the list).

We use the stack as follows: when we find an opening parentheses ('('),
bracket ('['), or brace ('{'), we put it on the stack. When we
find a closing one, we check the topmost item on the stack, and
make sure that it matches the closing one. If not, we print an
error. Like this:

```
def check_parentheses(f):
    stack = list()
    for line in f:
        for c in line:
            if c == '(' or c == '[' or c == '{':
                stack.append(c)
            elif c == ')':
                if stack[-1] != '(':
                    print 'Error: unmatched )'
                else:
                    stack.pop()
            elif c == ']':
                if stack[-1] != '[':
                    print 'Error: unmatched ]'
                else:
                    stack.pop()
            elif c == '}':
                if stack[-1] != '{':
                    print 'Error: unmatched }'
                else:
                    stack.pop()
```

This now does find unmatched parentheses of various kinds. We
can improve it a little bit by reporting the line and column 
where we find the problem. We need a line number and column number
counter.

```
def error(c, line_number, column_number):
    print 'Error: unmatched', c, 'line', line_number, 'column', column_number

def check_parentheses(f):
    stack = list()
    line_number = 0
    for line in f:
        line_number = line_number + 1
        column_number = 0
        for c in line:
            column_number = column_number + 1
            if c == '(' or c == '[' or c == '{':
                stack.append(c)
            elif c == ')':
                if stack[-1] != '(':
                    error(')', line_number, column_number)
                else:
                    stack.pop()
            elif c == ']':
                if stack[-1] != '[':
                    error(']', line_number, column_number)
                else:
                    stack.pop()
            elif c == '}':
                if stack[-1] != '{':
                    error('}', line_number, column_number)
                else:
                    stack.pop()
```

Note also how I added a helper function, `error`, to do the actual
printing of the error message. If you want to change the error message,
you now only need to do it in one place.

Another thing to notice is that the cases for handling the closing
symbols are all very similar. We could make that to a function, too.

```
def check(stack, wanted, c, line_number, column_number):
    if stack[-1] != wanted:
        error(c, line_number, column_number)
    else:
        stack.pop()

def check_parentheses(f):
    stack = list()
    line_number = 0
    for line in f:
        line_number = line_number + 1
        column_number = 0
        for c in line:
            column_number = column_number + 1
            if c == '(' or c == '[' or c == '{':
                stack.append(c)
            elif c == ')':
                check(stack, '(', ')', line_number, column_number)
            elif c == ']':
                check(stack, '[', ']', line_number, column_number)
            elif c == '}':
                check(stack, '{', '}', line_number, column_number)
```

The program can be refined further, but this should suffice for now.
I'll include the whole code at the end.

Note that this program only cares about parentheses of various kinds.
If you really want to check a whole Python program for syntactic
correctness, you'll need to parse all of Python's syntax, and that
is pretty complicated, and too much for one Stack Overflow answer.
If that's what you really do want, please ask a followup question.

The whole program:

```
import sys

def error(c, line_number, column_number):
    print 'Error: unmatched', c, 'line', line_number, 'column', column_number

def check(stack, wanted, c, line_number, column_number):
    if stack[-1] != wanted:
        error(c, line_number, column_number)
    else:
        stack.pop()

def check_parentheses(f):
    stack = list()
    line_number = 0
    for line in f:
        line_number = line_number + 1
        column_number = 0
        for c in line:
            column_number = column_number + 1
            if c == '(' or c == '[' or c == '{':
                stack.append(c)
            elif c == ')':
                check(stack, '(', ')', line_number, column_number)
            elif c == ']':
                check(stack, '[', ']', line_number, column_number)
            elif c == '}':
                check(stack, '{', '}', line_number, column_number)

def main():
    filename = sys.argv[1]
    try:
        f = file(filename)
    except IOError:
        sys.stderr.write('Error: Cannot open file %s' % filename)
        sys.exit(1)
    check_parentheses(f)
    f.close()

main()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think if you change the:

```
            if line=='(':
                 c1=line.count('(')
            elif line==')':
                 c2=line.count(')')
            elif line=='[':
                 c3=line.count('[')
            elif line==']':
                 c4=line.count(']')
            elif line=='':
                break
```

to something like:

```
SearchFor = ['(', ')', '[', ']']
d = {}
for itm in SearchFor:
    d[itm] = line.count(itm)


# Then do the comparison
if d['['] == d[']'] and  d['('] == d[')']:
     print "Valid Syntax"
else:
     print "Invalid Syntax" #You could look at each to find the exact cause.
```

and the `While True:` as mentioned by others. I had missed that. :0)

Comment: i dont wanna count generally the '(', ')', '[', ']'
but actually compare them...thats why i have the next loop body

Comment: I'm sorry, I had completely mistyped the last part of the code. I've corrected it. This should better represent what you are trying to accomplish. The `d` variable should end up being something like `{'[':5, ']':5, '(':4, ')':4}` if both match.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the 'while True' line and this bit:

```
elif line=='':
    break
```

and then replace this:

```
for line in filename:
    line=f.readline()
```

with this:

```
for line in f:
```

Now you'll be looping over the lines in the file.

Next, replace all of these sorts of things:

```
if line=='(':
    c1=line.count('(')
```

with:

```
    c1+=line.count('(')
```

The if and elif lines are just preventing you from counting when you should. If the line doesn't have what you're looking for the count will be 0, which is fine.

That should at least get you closer to a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I believe, You are looking for balanced symbol checker. It is better to use stack.

1. Make an empty stack,
2. For each symbol in the string:

   2.1 If the symbol is an opening symbol, push it on the stack.

   2.2 If it is a closing symbol, then

   2.2.1 If the stack is empty, then it in false.

   2.2.2 If the top of the stack does not match the closing symbol, return false. [check this step if you are checking for matched braces]

   2.2.3 Pop the stack.
3. Return true if the stack is empty, otherwise false.

hth.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to ensure that they parens & braces are matched? That "[(])" fails? If not, you're along the right path, except that you need to change your "=" to "+=". You're discarding the values of previous lines.

Comment: I think the big problem is actually comparing the line to a single character to decide whether to count it up or not.

Comment: yes that: "[(])" doesnt fail!
where is the: "=" that you mean?
yes...i wanna count the parentheses!if the right ones=left ones then its right if not it gives a message "invalid syntax"
any ideas? 
thnxxxx

Comment: In what world is `[(])` syntactically valid?

Comment: Oh wait. I'm wrong. This code is terrible.

You need to check each character. What you're doing is ensuring that the *entire* line is equal to "(". On top of that, you're overwriting previous values & counts.

Try something like:
    sum([1 for i in line if i == '('])

Comment: To balance (lazily & incorrectly):
    sum([1 for i in a if i == '(']) + sum([-1 for i in a if i == ')'])

Answer (score 0):

My solution will try to help you understand a bit more precise way of doing this, and hopefully you'll learn a bit about data structures in the process.

To *properly* do this, you're going to want to use a [**stack**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(data_structure)). You'll want to pull out all instances of (, ), [, and ] (perhaps using a regular expression... hint) and go through the array that that generates:

Say your file is like this:

```
(this [is] foobar)
```

Your regular expression will yield this array:

```
['(', '[', ']', ')']
```

You will `pop(0)` off of this array into a stack.

**Algorithmically**:

1) Put all tags {(,),[,]} in an array.

2) For each element in the array, pop(0) from it and push it onto your stack. Test it against the element before it. If it closes the element before it, then pop() twice from the array (eg, if you have '(' on the stack, and the next element to be pushed onto the stack is a ')', ')' closes '(', so you pop them both.) If it doesn't, continue.

3) If your array is empty and your stack is empty when this is over, then your file is well formed. If it's not, then you have a poorly formed file {something like (foo[bar)] }.

**Bonus:** regular expression: REGEX = re.compile(r"\)\(\[\]"), REGEX.findall(your string to search). See more about regexes in Python [here](http://docs.python.org/howto/regex.html).

Comment: I see your stack based parser and raise you an LL* based parser.

Comment: -1 ... pop(0) is a nonsense. Secondly, there is no point pushing the input onto the stack under conditions where it is immediately going to be pulled off again.

Comment: Actually, pop(0) pops the first item of the array. Look in the Python docs. Secondly, the way I described is a standard way to parse tag-based documents like XML. It's not only a decent way to do it, but it's the algorithmically standard way described in at least a few algorithm texts. Sure, it can be made more efficient, but that's not the point here. Thanks for the -1...

Comment: Of course pop(0) pops the first (0) item of the list. The point is that it is totally unnecessary to remove any item from the input list. All you need to do is something like `for input_item in input_list:`. Parsing tag-based documents is irrelevant. All the parsing algorithms I have seen that use a stack base action on some function of the input element and the current top element of the parse stack (if any) ... if none, it's easier to test for, which your pseudocode doesn't.

Comment: So a downvote for a correctly functioning algorithm that doesn't work the way you'd like it?

Comment: It doesn't work correctly; you don't test for an empty stack. However the downvote was for the sheer ludicrousness of telling a n00b to do pop(0) from an "array". It's not a matter of leaving it to later optimisation; nobody but nobody should write pop(0) first up in this scenario. Compare your answer with Thillakan's.

Comment: Just tested. Algorithm works. We can debate on how bad it is to show a newbie a non-trivial data structure (Python's wonky array), but the algorithm does work. Can you give me an input for which it fails? I will improve my question with your aid, if you're willing to help rather than simply criticize.

Comment: None of your "we can debate" sentence makes much sense. If you are talking about array as in the array module, you shouldn't be. If you mean a list, call it that, and explain "wonky". In any case, the point was that you introduced pop(0) which is utter overkill; all that you need demand from your input is that you can iterate over it in original order.

Comment: About your algorithm: I've already told you: "you don't test for an empty stack". Help: Read Thillakan's answer, it works properly. However, here's an example: **ANY INPUT**. You say to push the incoming element onto the parse stack. Then "Test it against the element before it". You DON'T specify what to do if the stack is empty. First time up, there is no element before the just-pushed input item. You try to access parse_stack[-2] and crash with an IndexError. If "Algorithm works", either your implementation doesn't follow your answer, or you have a strange definition of "works".

Comment: "If it closes the element before it, then pop() twice from the array (eg, if you have '(' on the stack, and the next element to be pushed onto the stack is a ')', ')' closes '(', so you pop them both.) If it doesn't, continue." If there is no element before it, it doesn't pop the element before it, right? But I appreciate your attempt at providing a substantive argument this time: this is the sort of constructive criticism that could have gotten us somewhere earlier.

Answer (score 0):

All of these answers are wrong and will not work in all cases, so either use python parser e.g. tokenize etc or just use this

count = min(text.count("("), text.count(")"))